# Joomla 2.5: Display single article from list in shared module

Tags: joomla

I have a main menu with menu items that, when clicked dynamically displays content based on a category.

On the same page I have a section with a list of news articles (not related to any menu) which displays an intro text, each with a read-more button.

I'd like to click the read-more button and load the complete text where the content of the main menu is loaded (sharing the same module).

Right now, it simply loads the list of news articles.

What do I have to do to  1. only display the article I click and 2. show the complete text?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue every time when I use modules with content from any category on the Home Page. When I click on Read More, then the Home Page appears instead of the article.

The Solution is simple: I always create a "Hidden Menu" with Menu Manager and I create a Menu element as Category Blog Layout related to this category. This solution means the Hidden Menu module won't appear on the site, but the articles will with full text from any module used on the website.

Comment: Thx for your reply!
I still don't manage to make it work. What type of module do I need to use to make this work? Right now I'm using an Articles Category module, mode set to dynamic to achieve what I'm trying to do. I'm missing a piece of the puzzle somewhere...

Comment: I guess you are using few modules on the Home Page. Please visit these modules and set these to Home page only. It would be very helpful if you attach an image of your Module Manager page and please insert your template index.php. Maybe an if statement is missing from there.

Comment: Thx for you help!!!!
http://mockup.showcare.com/sc2012/joomla/hidden-menu-item.gif

http://mockup.showcare.com/sc2012/joomla/module-manager.gif

Template:
MAIN MENU
<div id="menu">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="pos-menu" />
</div>

OUTPUT CONTENT
<div id="mainContent">
      <div class="content"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="pos-content" /></div>
</div>

LIST OF NEWS ARTICLE WITH READMORE LINKS
<div id="news">
      <div class="news-headline">News & Events</div>
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="pos-news-events" />
</div>

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the homepage. When I click either of the readmore links on the right the output on the left looks like this:
http://mockup.showcare.com/sc2012/joomla/homepage-screenshot.gif